A question about exercise 5.25 from Atiyah - MacDonald
One part of the exercise is about proving a sort of generalization of Zariski's lemma that goes like:

If $A$ is a Jacobson ring, then every finitely generated $A$-algebra $B$ which is also a field is finitely generated as an $A$-module.

A proof starts like this. Let $f: A\to B$ be the homomorphism defining $B$, then $A'\equiv f(A)$ is Jacobson and an integral domain since $B$ is a field. In particular this implies that both nilradical and Jacobson radical of $A'$ are zero. Now the book hints at using a previous result (exercise 5.21):

$A \subset B$, $B$ integral domain, finitely generated over $A$. $\exists s\neq 0 \in A$, such that if $\Omega$ is an algebraically closed field and $f: A\to \Omega$ an homomorphism with $f(s)\neq 0$ then $f$ has an extension as a homomorphism $f: B\to \Omega$.

So let $s\neq 0\in A'$ from the proposition above. Since the Jacobson radical of $A'$ is zero there will be a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ not containing $s$ and a map $\pi: A\to A/\mathfrak{m}\equiv k\to \bar k$, where $\bar k$ is the algebraic closure of the field $k$ (and $\pi(s)\neq 0$). Now I should be able to extend this to a homomorphism $\pi: B \to \bar k$, which would be injective being $B$ a field.
I'm now confused as to how this can be possible unless $\mathfrak{m}$ is zero and $A'$ is itself a field since otherwise the restriction of the injection $\pi$ to $A'$ would not be injective.

I think you are right that $A'$ itself should be a field, and then maybe you can conclude the proof using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz?

Yeah, I guess if it is correct that $A'$ has to be a field, then one is under the hypothesis of Zariski's lemma and the thesis follows. But there must something very obvious I'm missing because also the wiki proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma) mentions injectivity of the extension...
